# ¿Qué hacer para que el zoom del navegador no afecte nuestro sitio web?

Tags: navegador-web, zoom

Hola comunidad quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para que nuestro sitio web no se vea afectado por el zoom que el usuario le da al navegador chrome o safari.

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero lo hizo el sitio web de [citibanamex](https://www.banamex.com/) 
Si ustedes le dan zoom +, el sitio se va ajustando hasta ser mobile.
Pero si le dan zoom -, el sitio se ajusta al mismo tamaño sin ser más pequeño.

Me metí al código y vi el meta

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Pero le falta algo más que no encuentro. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Según mis pocos conocimientos para esto se debe implementar el uso de porcentajes y medidas variables como [em](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp) para los textos y las [mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) para el responsive